# Cant connect to Mysql server ; Can't create/write the pid file

Tags: mysql, database

Hello I cant seem to connect to my mysql server, i get the following error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

when i checked the logs , it showed me the following :

```
130314 12:36:16 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Table 'plugin' is read only
130314 12:36:16 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
130314 12:36:16  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130314 12:36:16  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130314 12:36:16  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 13 1336891001
130314 12:36:16 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/live.pid' (Errcode: 13)
130314 12:36:16 [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 13):

I had sample problem with mysql. I run under root permission but don't known why this error happen. The problem is mysql user don't have permission to create pid file in `/var/run/mysqld`. 
Full log could look like:

```
140812 09:35:53 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140812  9:35:53  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
140812  9:35:53  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140812  9:35:53  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 197396648
140812  9:35:53 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid' (Errcode: 13)
140812  9:35:53 [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: Permission denied
140812 09:35:53 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

So the solution is assign mysql user to this directory:

```
# chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

and then start mysqld

```
# service mysqld start
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem under Redhat and [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20170426171414/http://crashmag.net/change-the-default-mysql-data-directory-with-selinux-enabled) had the steps to switch the mysql directory.

```
service mysqld stop
mkdir /srv/mysql/
chown mysql:mysql /srv/mysql
```

edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and set `datadir=/srv/mysql` & `socket=/srv/mysql/mysql.sock`

Additional steps are required if you are using SELinux and then finally start the server

```
service mysqld start
```

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: 404 for that page. You were saying?

Comment: By reading just the link URL, "change the default mysql data directory with selinux enabled", I pressume OP's problem was a SElinux issue.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, this error is because we have wrong permissions in log file /var/log/mysqld.log

```
chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

Answer (score 0):

After 2 hours of missing quality Netflix programming I just went ahead and:

```
chmod -R 777 /usr/local/mysql
chmod -R 777 /usr/local/mysql-5.6.19-osx10.7-x86_64
```

... on OSX Mavericks.  PITA.

Comment: Changing to 777 of course works (tried and it did), but surely there must be a less-permissive way of doing this.

Comment: 775 ? worked for me though...local machine, nothing to hide